# How to display the ui from different apps in same container (C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to create several applications in c++, each one having its own GUI.
All the applications will be launched by another app (app A). This app will open all the GUI apps.
What I want is that the UI content of each app to be displayed in the same window. The user can browse the ui for each app using tabs. The user should only open app A, and A will open each UI app and displayed their interface in the same window.
Can someone give me some direction in how to achive this? I'm developing in Visual Studio 2010 C++. (Windows applications)

Comment: Souds like an XY problem. Why do the separate child apps need to be separate? It might be easier to make all windows part of a single app.

Comment: If a child app crashes, only the functionality from that app will be broken, while the main app with the remaining child apps will continue working. The main app can also restart the child app that crashed.

Comment: Start by integrating/making a virtual machine running Windows into your app then start the child processes in that.

Comment: Isn't it feasible for you to segregate all the UI in one app? It would be a clean and reliable solution to use MVC pattern and implement the View-Controller communication relaying on a convenient IPC (Inter Process Communication) technique for your platform.

Comment: The "crash" problem is better solved by fixing the crash TBH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done if your ui applications can communicate its windows handles to host application. And in your host application you will need to reparent those windows into the tabs. Something like this:

```
// hWnd is the window we want to embed
long style = ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);

style |= WS_CHILD;
style &= ~WS_POPUP;
style &= ~WS_CAPTION;
style &= ~WS_THICKFRAME;

SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
SetParent(hWnd, hostHWnd() /* this returns HWND of the host window */);

SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, hostWidth(), hostHeight(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

You can communicate windows handles via named pipes, for instance.

But be ready to experience some problems when doing this. For instance you will need to resize embedded windows when the host window is resized (by calling SetWindowPos as in example).

Comment: You did not point out a more severe problem: Reparenting windows boils down to calling `AttachThreadInput`, i.e. what used to be asynchronous applications now shares a synchronous input queue. If those applications are not prepared for this scenario (and they usually aren't) things will go downhill from there.

Comment: Well right, the behavior depends very much on the embedded application. However when both (embedded and host) applications are under developer's control, things usually work nice (had a successful experience embedding C# apps into native C++ hosts). I am wondering how ActiveX out-of-process controls embedding is implemented at low level...